# Create a file or go to line n of that file

Tags: c

I've been working on this C programming assignment and I just can't seem to find out why it is not behaving the way I expect it to be behaving. The program is supposed to run, and there are 3 possible options for commands `0`, `-n`, and `n`, where n is a positive integer.

When I execute the program, and type `0` as the command (which should create a file if one has not already been created) it just loops back to asking me to enter a command.

The commands `-n` and `n` go to the line specified by `n` and seeks to it. `n` prints line n, whereas `-n` prints all lines from n onward until it can no longer read from the text file.

Would greatly appreciate it if somebody could give me a hint or two and steer me in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256
#define LINESIZE 1024

int write(FILE *fp);
int grade_validation(int grade);
int id_validation(char studentid[]);
int display(FILE *fp, int cmd);
int display_all(FILE *fp, int cmd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        perror("invalid number of args");
        return 1;
    } else {
        FILE *fp;
        if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "wb+")) == 0) {
            perror("fopen");
            return 1;
        }
        write(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}

int write(FILE* fp) {
    int grade;
    char studentid[BUFSIZE];
    char input[BUFSIZE];
    int cmd;
    while(1) {
        printf("Input 0 to append, n to view, or -n to view all records starting from n.\n");
        if(!fgets(input, LINESIZE, stdin)) {
            clearerr(stdin);
            return 0;
        }
        if((sscanf(input, "%d", &cmd) == 1)) {
            if(cmd == 0) {
                if((id_validation(studentid)) != 1 || (grade_validation(&grade) == -1)) {
                    continue;
                }
                fprintf(fp, "%s %3d ", studentid, grade);
            } else if(cmd > 0) {
                display(fp, cmd);
            } else if(cmd < 0) {
                display_all(fp, cmd);
            }
        }
    }
}   

int grade_validation(int grade) {
    char input[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    if(grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
        return 1;
    } 
    if(sscanf(input, "%d", &grade) == 1) {
        if((grade_validation(grade)) == 1) {
            if(fprintf(fp, "%3d", grade) == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("Grade recorded successfully.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int id_validation(char studentid[]) {
    char input[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    size_t i = 0;
    if(strlen(studentid) == 9) {
        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(isdigit(studentid[i])) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(sscanf(input, "%s", studentid) == 1) {
        if((id_validation(studentid)) == 1) {
            if(fprintf(fp, "%s", studentid) == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("Student ID recorded successfully.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int display(FILE *fp, int cmd) {
    char studentid[BUFSIZE];
    int grade;
    if(!fgets(cmd, BUFSIZE, fp)) {
        clearerr(stdin);
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(fp, cmd, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %3d", studentid, grade);
}

int display_all(FILE *fp, int cmd) {
    char studentid[BUFSIZE];
    int grade;
    if(!fgets(cmd, BUFSIZE, fp)) {
        clearerr(stdin);
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(fp, cmd, SEEK_SET);
    while((sscanf(studentid, grade, "%s %3d", cmd)) != EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %3d", studentid, grade);
    }
}
```

Comment: What attempts have you made to debug the program?

Comment: Why do you use `fgets(input, *LINESIZE*, stdin)`? You have to use `fgets(input, BUFSIZE, stdin)`, because `input` covers 256, not 1024 bytes!  Also your "id_validation" looks suspicious.  You return "true," already, when the first character of the id is a digit.

Comment: the format for the student id should be a######## so should i really be checking if strlen(studentid) == 9 and then doing a check to see if studentid[0] = 'a' before go into the for loop to check the remaining array values?

Comment: You have to open the file with mode "w+b," not "wb+".  Your calls of `fgets` are wrong in lines 101 and 112.  Your call of `sscanf` is wrong in line 117.

Comment: @user1218982 Yes, you should.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to validate the uninitialized `studentid` and `grade`.

Also, you pass `&grade` to `grade_validation`, which expects and integer.
This would cause a warning, which should make you figure out something is wrong. Always compile with warnings enabled, and treated as errors (in gcc, `-Wall -Werror`).

Comment: Indeed, there are (some) warnings issued by GCC that aren't problematic, but until you have a good feel for what can be safely ignored, consider ALL warnings to be errors.

Comment: The code doesn't work at all, there are tons of failures in it.  Removing the warnings of this code makes `gcc` print out even more warnings/errors...

Comment: Hm, maybe I will try doing that -- may help me figure out  fundamentally why my code isn't working (though in my mind there seems to be no problems)